# MSBuild task running in separate appdomain cannot load assemblies

Tags: .net, msbuild

I have an MSBuild Task that has the `LoadInSeparateAppDomainAttribute` and inherits from `AppDomainIsolatedTask`.

This task runs after a successful build. It loads the newly compiled assembly and performs some work with it. So a separate appdomain is required because otherwise Visual Studio will load the assembly and lock it.

However, the created appdomain is not aware of the `Web.config` file of the application. This config contains binding redirects required to successfully load the assembly's referenced DLLs.

Is there a way to add binding redirects to the appdomain programmatically?

Comment: Does your task take input variables?

Comment: Yes, it has inputs for the web application's source directory, bin directory, and also an input containing the path to save some generated output to.

Comment: It's tempting to remove `LoadInSeparateAppDomainAttribute` and create the appdomain manually. Then I could specify the config, etc, explicitly.

Comment: Are you specifying a config file for the newly created appdomain?